# The Stack Overflow newsletter is still using the old icon

Tags: bug, design, logo, newsletter

Saw this in my inbox today:

[image]

The email shouldn't be using the old logo.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @DaveZych:  I'm fairly sure caching isn't to blame. Not this time.

Comment: Try [the wheel of blame](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldvwp8uv/1/embedded/result/)  to find someone...

Comment: It looks like this is happening due to a problem with the C# code.

Comment: @Makoto I feel like it's kind of obligatory now for all of the *this logo is the old logo* bugs posted here.